# scheduling data downloading in iPhone app

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode5

I am developing an iPhone app using Xcode 5.

I want my app to download some files once a week. Can someone direct me to right direction?

Comment: Just check on start up of the app if a week has passed and if so download your file.

Comment: You want this to happen with the app in background all the time, or if the user opens the app, to check if new files are available and download everything ?

Comment: I want to happen this in background, check after a week that if file is updated on the server. If yes then download it and notify the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on iOS7 you can use the new background fetching mode:

- To register, include the `UIBackgroundModes` key with the fetch value in your app’s `Info.plist` file.
- When your app is launched, call the [`setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval%3a) method to determine how often it receives update messages.
- Implement the [`application:performFetchWithCompletionHandler:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application%3aperformFetchWithCompletionHandler%3a) method in your app delegate.